# Передача данных-событий в Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Здравствуйте начал изучать Vue, немогу разобраться у меня есть 2 компонента, 1-modal и 2-page, в `page` есть кнопка 'buy' при нажатие на нее должна передаваться boolean значения в компонент `modal`, а в `modal` есть кнопка `Close` и `X` а при нажатие на них модалка должна закрыться. понимаю что это делается при помощи $emit но я еще не понял.

Comment: Какая у тебя версия Vue? Так как с версии 3 сам `emitter` уже является отдельной библиотекой и `emit` был удален, если же версия вторая снизу есть нужный тебе ответ

Comment: 3 версия , я уже разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Входные данные можно передавать через `props`-ы
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

В вашем случае, возможно, будет достаточно использовать для переключения показа `v-if="showModal"`

При закрытии в модальном окне при клике на кнопку можно генерировать событие, например:
`$emit('close')`

В родительском ловить его, например:
`@close="onClose"`

И в методе `onClose` отработать закрытие окна. Например, `this.showModal = false`